# show/hide magento cart in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, e-commerce

I'm working on a site which is primarily based on wordpress but uses magento to deal with its e-commerce (not my choice, it's how the site is setup).

When a product is selected, it links through to the magento shopping cart. We have a site wide "View Cart" link in the head of the site which links to the magento cart. What I'd like to do is to hide this link if the cart is empty.

Working soley in magento I could use this to hide the link:

```
<?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
<?php if ($_cartQty >0): ?>
<a href="link">link to cart</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

but it doesn't work for wordpress... Is there a way to get the cart count from magento into wp to then use something along the lines of...

```
<?php if (sizeof($cart) > 1)) : ?>
<a href="link">link to cart</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: your code is right. Did you include in wordpress's code `app/Mage.php` with start of `Mage::app()`?

Comment: my php isn't particularly advanced and mage isnt something I've come across before. how would I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once '../app/Mage.php'; //root to app/Mage.php of magento
Mage::app(); //run
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); //load session
$count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(); //read count itemes in cart
$total = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //read total in cart
if($count==0){
    echo '<a href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl("web").'checkout/cart">Cart is empty</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl("web").'checkout/cart">'.$count.' item(s) with total '.Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($total, false).'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thats great thank you. One issue I'm having is that when you add something to the basket the site doesn't load? (it may be something I've done wrong)